# Proving that a number is rational $(210.12)?$

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

I am a little lost regarding how to prove that a number is rational.

I am given a number $210.12$, and I have to prove that it is rational.
Looking at the definition of rational numbers, it can be expressed by a fraction of two integers. In this case
$$210.12 = \frac{5253}{25}$$

How do I proceed from here? Any advice and guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Since $5253$ and $25$ are integers, you have already proven this fact.

Comment: How could one express this without a calculator to find the fraction?

Comment: $210.12=210+\frac {12}{100}$ and the sum of two rationals is rational.

Comment: Since this fraction terminates, we can write $210.12=\dfrac {21012}{100}$.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the Canonical Form of Rational Number definition  $\mathbb{Q}$  $$\mathbb{Q}=\{\frac ab|a,b \in \mathbb{Z},b\neq0,(a,b)=1 \}$$  as an example $\frac68 \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ but if you simplify $\frac68$ to $\frac34$ there is $(3,4)=1\\(6,8)\neq1$
so $\frac34 \in \mathbb{Q}$ .

hope it helps you

Comment: Since $\frac34=\frac68$, your $\mathbb Q$ is ill-defined.

Comment: @player3236. He has the condition $(a, b) = 1$ meaning that the greatest common divisor should equal $1$.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, that is precisely what causes the ill-definedness. We now have $\mathbb Q \ni \frac34 = \frac 68 \notin \mathbb Q$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Your convention on how fractions are used is not standard. It's pretty standard that $\frac{6}{8}$ means "6 divided by 8" and that $\frac{3}{4}$ means "3 divided by 4", and that they are equal.